# How to edit columns in .CSV files using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

# Url file Website
url = 'https://......CSV'

# Download file
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    url, "F:\.....A.CSV")

csvFilePath = "F:\.....A.CSV"

df = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, sep='\t')

rows=[0,1,2,3]
df2 = df.drop(rows, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(
    r'F:\....New_A.CSV')
```

I tried doing this in code but it's making columns merge into a single column.
What I'm going to do is remove the top row from the left as shown in the picture.

[image]

**I found a problem `sep='\t' change to sep=','`**

Comment: Use `skiprows=5` attribute of `pd.read_csv(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, sep='\t')
```

by:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, sep='\t', skiprows=5)
```

Comment: The row has been removed, but when I export the file using the df.to_csv column it merges into a single column.

pic : https://ibb.co/MZ3wSMx